# Mean of N nearest neighbors for each pixel in a LARGE raster

Tags: gdal, buffer, bigtiff

I a have a large raster (.vrt)...

```
Size is 70780, 102676
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["UTM Zone 32, Northern Hemisphere",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
...
```

with about 450000000 pixels that are non-NODATA.

For each non-NODATA pixel, I am trying to compute the mean Z value in a 3km neighborhood (see image).
Neighbor pixels used to compute the mean are non-NODATA pixels too.

[image]

Although I have found a solution to calculate the average of the neighbors on small subsamples of the raster (an R-based solution), it is very slow. Incredibly slow to try to scale it to the large raster.

I understand that GDAL may be the tool that accomplishes the task faster. However, I'm pretty new to using it and still can't figure out how to do it.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What does NA mean? Nodata?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding.
Yes, it means NODATA. I edited it.